# What part of speech would "away" be?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, phrasal-verbs, parts-of-speech

"The captain gave *away* his authority"

In this example would *away* be an adverb or an adjective?

Comment: *Away* [is an adverb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/away). It's evolved into an adjective. But here, it's clearly an adverb of motion as it describes how the authority (object) was given. There may be more of a question about "The captain gave his authority away" (cf "The captain painted his house red") but even there, *gave* doesn't lend itself to adjectives.

Comment: I'd argue it's so coherent with the simplex verb that it doesn't make sense to classify it independently. Such words have the default label 'particle'.

Comment: _Give away_ is a phrasal verb that undergoes particle shift: _Give the car away/Give it away_ vs _Give away the car_/*_Give away it._ So it doesn't matter what POS it might be by itself; it's the construction that counts. As Edwin says, it's usually called a "particle". If you need another label, call it an intransitive preposition.

Answer (score 3):

As Edwin Ashworth says, the tendency among current grammarians is to call *away* in this sort of context (*give away, put away,send away*) a 'particle'.

That strikes me as counsel of despair—it's merely replacing the traditional catchall trashcan term *adverb* with a new catchall trashcan term.

I suggest that these 'particles' are in fact intransitive prepositions—prepositions which stand alone, without obliques, and thus constitute in themselves preposition phrases.

Historically, in fact, *away* **was** a preposition phrase: as in similar words like *aboard, adrift, aground, ahead, aloft*, the *a-* is a worn-down form of *an* = ModE "on". Many modern intransitive prepositions have preserved their prepositions more discernibly (*downhill, upstairs, overhead, underfoot*), others have even collapsed their prepositions into their obliques (*home, east*).

This is I think clearly justifiable with verbs of motion and caused motion, where *away* plays the same syntactic role as ordinary preposition phrases (*go to London/away, put it on the table/away*). The occurrence with *give* is only a little more opaque; Goldberg, *Constructions*, 1995, notes the very close affinity between ditransitive constructions, which usually allow the Recipient to be realized as a PP rather than an IO ("dative alternation"), and caused-motion constructions. And quite a few intransitive prepositions besides *to* are commonly used with *give*: *give back, give in, give on, give out, give over, give out, give up*. Note that many of these prepositions also license transitive uses, and that many of these idioms are employed both with and without direct objects.

I suggest that this is a perfectly conventional use of an always-intransitive preposition as a locative complement of *give* designating the direction or (indeterminate) goal of the gift.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and for "counsel of despair". Is *we* misplaced in "we quite a few"?

Comment: @deadrat Thank you, especially for the untidiedup edit.